# PE FILE section read in C

Tags: c, pe

I need to read PE file. I need to search word in PE file. Search is required to cover only the sections with the “executable” flag. And I need to specify the section where the word found. How can I do this in C? I hope you can help me. And I cannot use 3rd party libraries. This is my task and this is the rule..

I mean a searching string in sections with the "executable" flags. I do not want to search string in non executable parts.

Comment: pecoff Spec: https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/5/9C5B2167-8017-4BAE-9FDE-D599BAC8184A/pecoff.docx

Comment: @joshpoley wow this is too long

Answer (score 4):

You will need to read the [PE header format](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/5/9C5B2167-8017-4BAE-9FDE-D599BAC8184A/pecoff.docx) posted by @josh poley in the comments to figure out how to find the section header pointers.

The tasks you need to perform (roughly) are:

1. Read the PE header at the beginning of the executable and find the pointer to the section headers. There are several posts about this on Stack Exchange already. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261929/getting-text-section-header-of-pe-file) to find the section headers.
2. Iterate through the section headers to find which ones are executable, using the Characteristics field. That field is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) - look for the IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE field in Section Flags.
3. For the executable sections, use the raw addresses from the section header to identify where they are located and search these memory ranges for the string you are trying to identify.

You'll do this in C using a ton of pointer arithmetic. Or, the commonsense shortcut would be to import the Microsoft header files that describe the relevant structs, like they do in [this Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182852/read-pe-files-in-c) That way you can declare a pointer of the relevant type and access its members by calculating their offsets by hand.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer. I found some code for finding sections and addresses. But I do not know how to read section.  I already read the link in 1. meterial.

Comment: But I do not figure out.  I have output like this:
Section Header name :               .text
ActualSize of code or data :        0x49937
Virtual Address(RVA) :              0x1000
Size of raw data (rounded to FA) :  0x49a00
Pointer to Raw Data :               0x400
Pointer to Relocations :            0
Pointer to Line numbers :           0
Number of relocations :             0
Number of line numbers :            0
Characteristics :                   Contains executable code, Readable,

How can read just this section?

Comment: @sadMarry You're asking how to do this in C? There are a couple of ways you could do it. One would be to read the whole file into a buffer, and then access that buffer at the offset of the pointer to raw data. You could copy the data from there to the end of the section into a new buffer and search only that new buffer for your target string.